# Xpages javascript object error calling simple function

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I am getting the following error when trying to make a simple call from the beforeRenderResponse event of an XPage:

Error calling method 'IsLoggedIn()' on an object of type 'object [Javascript Object]'

I can't figure out why it gives me that error, especially when I am not using an object.  Here's how I have it working:

XPage BeforeRenderResponse:

```
ProductFinderInit();   (which is in the SiteSpecific.jss library, and included in resources on XPage)
```

In SiteSpecific.jss:

```
import Common;

function ProductFinderInit() {
...
  viewScope.IsLoggedIn = IsLoggedIn();
...
```

In Common.jss (which is also resource on XPage):

```
function IsLoggedIn() {
  var userName:NotesName = session.createName(@UserName());
  if (userName.getCommon() === "Anonymous") return false;
  else return true;
}
```

So it's really a simple call, which is why I'm confused on the error.  The really confusing thing is that it doesn't happen every time, only occasionally.  Any help would be great!

Comment: try changing this line
viewScope.IsLoggedIn =IsLoggedIn() ;
to
viewScope.put("IsLoggedIn",IsLoggedIn())

Comment: Can we start putting these suggestions in answers instead of comments so that these questions stop showing up as unanswered, please?

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be that viewScope.**IsLoggedIn** = **IsLoggedIn**(); has the same names.
Try to change at least one of them.

Also try to write into you methods some **try catch** with error printing.